# Determining which Lie algebras in a given list are (pairwise) isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

> For each pair of the following Lie algebras over $\Bbb R$, decide whether or not they are isomorphic:
>
> 1. the Lie algebra $\Bbb R^3$, where the Lie bracket is given by the vector product;
> 2. the upper triangular $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\Bbb R$;
> 3. the strictly upper triangular $3 \times 3$ matrices over $\Bbb R$;
> 4. $L = \{x \in \mathfrak{gl}(3, \Bbb R) : x^t = −x)\}$.

So far I'm pretty sure the upper triangular and strictly upper triangular matrices are not isomorphic, because the Lie algebra of strictly upper triangular matrices is nilpotent and the Lie algebra of upper triangular matrices are not.

Also, for $x^t$ in (4), does this just mean $x$ to any number $t$, or does $t$ have a specific meaning in an abstract algebra context?

If it is any number $t$, then I have $x=0$ and $x=-1$ as valid x values for that set, where $0=-0$, and $-1$ raised to any even integer $= 1$.

Working on this further, I believe that (2) is not isomorphic to any other, because it is of dimension $2$, where all others are of dimension $3$.

Comment: How about calculating $[L,L]$ in each case? And also, please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: As for your last question, I'm almost sure that $x^t$ in (iv) means the transpose of the matrix $x$. In general your idea of looking at nilpotency is good; I second the Lord's comment; also, try to show that (i) has no nilpotent elements at all. There might be an isomorphism between (i) and (iv).

Comment: Thank you! My linear/abstract algebra background is weak so I sometimes get caught on notational things.

Comment: @Rusk I've taken the liberty of formatting the post. I made numerous changes, so please verify that I've preserved your intended meaning. (If not, please adjust as necessary---feel free to ask if you have questions about how to use MathJax to modify this post.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that (3) is nilpotent but (2) is not, and hence they are not isomorphic.

When you calculated that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{n}_3$ in (3) is nilpotent ($\mathfrak{n}_3$ is called the [Heisenberg algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Lie_algebra)), you computed that its derived Lie algebra $[\mathfrak{n}_3, \mathfrak{n}_3]$ is
$$[\mathfrak{n}_3, \mathfrak{n}_3] = \left\{\pmatrix{\cdot&\cdot&b\\&\cdot&\cdot\\&&\cdot} : b \in \Bbb R \right\} \cong \Bbb R .$$

This suggests computing the derived Lie algebra $$[\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g}]$$ for the Lie algebras in (1) and (4) and comparing them to those of (2) and (3), which recovers Lord Shark the Unknown's hint in the comments.

It is not true, by the way, that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{t}_2$ in (2) has dimension $2$; it has dimension $3$, since it has basis
$$\left\{\pmatrix{a&\cdot\\&\cdot}, \pmatrix{\cdot&b\\&\cdot}, \pmatrix{\cdot&\cdot\\&c}\right\} .$$ Putting your intuition more precisely: The inclusion map $\mathfrak{t}_2 \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(2, \Bbb R)$ is a $2$-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{t}_2$, whereas the inclusion map $\mathfrak{n}_3 \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(3, \Bbb R)$ is a $3$-dimensional representation.

Finally, it was mentioned in the comments, but for a matrix $x \in \mathfrak{gl}(n, \Bbb R)$, $x^t$ just denotes transpose of $x$.

(In the last two comments, we used the (canonical) identification of $\mathfrak{gl}(n, \Bbb R)$ with the space $M(n, \Bbb R)$ of $n \times n$ matrices, equipped with the usual matrix commutator as Lie bracket.)

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying with regards to dimension, and I went and studied this more to improve my understanding. Now I see, they all have dimension 3.

Comment: I believe I've solved this now. None of them are isomorphic. i) is neither solvable nor nilpotent, where all the others are. iii) is nilpotent, and none of the others are. (ii) and (iv) are both solvable, but [L,L] for (iv) is not contained in (ii), so they are not isomorphic. For iv you wind up with 0's along the diagonal, three distinct elements on one side of the diagonal and their negatives on the other. I think this is correct unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @Rusk: How is (4) solvable?

Comment: Your description of the elements of Lie algebra (4)---which we usually denote $\mathfrak{so}(3, \Bbb R)$---is correct, but the algebra is not solvable. That point notwithstanding, the reasoning is regarding (2) and (4) is not correct. The map $x \mapsto -x^T$ is an isomorphism from $\mathfrak{s}_2$ to its image, but neither algebra is contained inside the other as a subset. Since we're interested here in identifying Lie algebras *up to isomorphism*, identification of one algebra as a concrete subalgebra of another algebra in general is not enough to draw conclusions about isomorphism.